# como acessar o json?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Acho que a coisa mais simples é acessar uma chave e um valor no json, porém a semanas eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso... ele retorna o json certinho pelo ajax mas quando vou tentar acessar não da.
Obs: sou meio leigo e estou aprendendo.

segue codigo:

```
function getjson(){
console.log('Recuperando post');
$.post("sistema/getpost.php", 'get',
    function(post){
        // aqui é a cagada que estou fazendo (quando tiro o stringify ele nem aparece)
        var obj = JSON.stringify(post);

        var cont = obj.conteudo;
        var color = obj.cor;
        var like = obj.curtidas;
        var follow = obj.follow;
        var situacao = obj.situacao;

        // esse é o card onde contera os dados
        var posthtml = '<section class=" animated slideInLeft section--center mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--6-col--phone mdl-grid demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-grid--no-spacing" style="margin-bottom:20px; background-color:'+color+';"><div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" style="margin-top:0px; min-height:150px; width:100%; background-color:'+color+';"><div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style=" width:100%;"><h4 style="text-align:center; margin-top:30px; background-color:'+color+';">'+cont+'</h4></div><div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border"><div class="quem"><p>'+follow+'</p></div><div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div><button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored "><i class="material-icons" style="margin-top:0px; font-size:24px;">chat_bubble</i><span>523</span></button><button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored " ><i class="material-icons" style="margin-top:0px; font-size:24px;">favorite</i><span>'+like+'</span></button></div></div></section>';

        // aqui é em qual das paginas ele colocara o card
        $( "#tab-1" ).append(posthtml);

    }); }
```

[image: Provando que ele ta retornando Json..]

Obs2: quando eu estava passando html direto não dava esse erro mas ai me disseram que não é viavel e nem funcional fazer isso ai eu mudei para ajax com json.
Agradeço qualquer ajuda

Comment: Não é `stringify` mas sim `parse`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [JSON tem dois métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

- `stringify`, para transformar um objeto com *Primitivos* numa *String*
- `parse`, para transformar uma *String* em formato *JSON* num objeto

Assim o que deves usar é `.parse()` e não `.stringify()` pois o servidor retorna uma *String* *JSON* e não um objeto.

Contudo podias usar `$.getJSON` e simplificas a coisa:

```
$.getJSON('sistema/getpost.php', 'get', function(obj){
    var cont = obj.conteudo;
    // etc...
```